# mongoose save (example from their website not working)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have my file to add data to mongo via mongoose :

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var mongoDB = 'mongodb://myuser:mypass@ds145293.mlab.com:45293/employees';
mongoose.connect(mongoDB);
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'MongoDB connection error:'))
db.once('open',function(){
    console.log('connected')
    var kittySchema = mongoose.Schema({
        name: String
      });
    var Kitten = mongoose.model('Kitten', kittySchema);
    var fluffy = new Kitten({ name: 'fluffy' });
    fluffy.save(function (err, fluffy) {
        if (err) return console.error(err);
        console.log('saved');
      });
})
mongoose.connection.close()
```

Copied almost verbatim from mongoose site.I am able to connect to the database but i dont get the 2nd console log.I have a db but no collections.Is this the problem?

Comment: No, if there is no collection one will be created when saving.

Comment: Ok.Any idea what is the problem then?

Comment: It cant complete the save before you close the database

Comment: Ah yes,the callback function!Its working now i just move the close connection inside the callback.THanks!

Answer (score 1):

Replace `mongoose.Schema` with `new Schema` and also I don't think this `mongoose.Promise = global.Promise` is required.

Comment: Aha, that's why I got IDE warnings. It does run without new however. It has a `if (!(this instanceof Schema)) {    return new Schema(obj, options);  }`. Not the first time someone tried to run that without new :p

Comment: And that promise thing is from the old documentation, I'm sure: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/4.x/docs/promises.html#plugging-in-your-own-promises-library

Comment: @ippi You know better sir. I'm also in my first steps of MongoDB and mongoose. Please guide.

Comment: But I thought Promise was not required so I said that and yeah that can be done, I just checked but it's not suggested now.

Comment: Sorry I'm being unclear!  I just mean that OP must have gotten it from there and it might depend on node/mongoose version. But you are correct!

Comment: Okay in that case. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It cant complete the save before you close the database. There are many options to wait for the save. I like async/await.

edit: sorry that was too quick. Updated example.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var mongoDB = 'mongodb://localhost/something';

async function run() {
    await mongoose.connect(mongoDB);
    console.log('connected')
    var kittySchema = new mongoose.Schema({ name: String }); 
    var Kitten = mongoose.model('Kitten', kittySchema);
    var fluffy = new Kitten({ name: 'fluffy' });
    await fluffy.save();
    console.log('saved');
    mongoose.connection.close();
}

run();
```

Or you can just move the close to after you have saved:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var mongoDB = 'mongodb://localhost/something';

mongoose.connect(mongoDB);
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'MongoDB connection error:'))
db.once('open', function () { 
    console.log('connected')
    var kittySchema = new mongoose.Schema({name: String });
    var Kitten = mongoose.model('Kitten', kittySchema);
    var fluffy = new Kitten({ name: 'fluffy' });
    fluffy.save(function (err, fluffy) {
        if (err) return console.error(err);
        console.log('saved');
        mongoose.connection.close();
    });
})
```